# jQuery working in firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me why the following code works in firefox but not chrome? to test this out on a page check out this [page](https://authoritytactical.com/shop/manufacturer/axts/axts-raptor-5-56-cerakote-fde-tungsten-bronze/) on my site and change the colors. Wanting to swap the images if a retina display is detected...

Here's my code:

```
    jQuery('#pa_color').click(function(){
 var monkey = jQuery('.jck-wt-images__image').attr('src')                   
if (monkey !== undefined) {


if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
  if (jQuery('.jck-wt-images__image').attr('src').contains('@2x')) {


}else{
      jQuery('img.jck-wt-thumbnails__image, img.jck-wt-images__image').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
  return attr.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '@2x$&');
});
}
  }
  }
  });
```

Also, I'd rather use .change instead of .click (so that it will work right on the mobile version of my site) but that didn't work at all...

Comment: I'm trying it in Chrome, what should I look for as the symptom?

Comment: I tried FF and Chrome and didn't notice any difference. I'm not on a Retina display, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the issue - you misuse the `.contains()` method here -

**customjquery.js - Line 8**

`if (jQuery('.jck-wt-images__image').attr('src').contains('@2x')) {..}`

What you should use is -

`if (jQuery('.jck-wt-images__image').attr('src').indexOf('@2x') >= 0) {..}`

What `$.contains()` is really for -

> The `$.contains()` method returns true if the DOM element provided by the second argument is a descendant of the DOM element provided by the first argument, whether it is a direct child or nested more deeply. Otherwise, it returns false. **Only element nodes are supported;** if the second argument is a text or comment node, `$.contains()` will return false.

**[Source](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)**